# Is there any way to represent discrete signal having infinite non-zero terms (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

for example input signal x[n] ={ 2^n , n>=0 }
{ 0  , else  }

and actually i would like to take convolution this input signal ...

but there's a problem that it has infinite range

so , if there are some ways to represent that input signal

Could you answer me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand this  `x[n] ={ 2^n , n>=0 } { 0 , else }`

But in general when dealing with infinity your best bet is usually generators. So if the above means a pattern that goes 1248163264 then you could try something like this:

```
def generator(NUM):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield NUM ** i
        i += 1


gen_obj = generator(2)

n = 8
pattern = []

for _ in range(n):
    pattern.append(str(next(gen_obj)))

print("".join(pattern))
```

So you can change n to any number to display as many as you need (and you can call next(gen_obj) as much as you need)

However, there is no direct way to display anything that is infinite in python, if you mean it in the way that a sigma can be used to represent a sum to infinity.